# Wise Installer not removing old files on upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade, wise

We have a legacy installer that was built with Wise, and we have a situation where some .ASP files were replaced with corresponding .INC files to deal with security concerns; so during the upgrade, those old .ASP files must be removed. It's working in one of the directories, but in the other two directories, the old .ASP files are still there after the upgrade.

For all of the directories in the website, there is a RemoveFile entry that tells the installer to remove all of the files during uninstall, so I would have thought that would be enough to get the installer to remove those old files, but apparently not.

In an attempt to fix the problem, I added RemoveFile entries that remove the specific files on install and tried the upgrade again, but even that didn't work.

Short of writing a custom action to get rid of those files, does anyone have any ideas on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my problem wasn't MSI-related. One of the custom actions in the install was backing up all of the web site files so that they could be restored by another custom action later in the upgrade, which was causing most of the .ASP files that we wanted to be removed to be put back in. In the one directory where the old .ASP file appeared to have been removed, it was because that directory was hidden and, so, was not backed up and, therefore, not restored. Between the backup and restore, the MSI was actually doing its job and deleting everything from the old build prior to the new stuff being installed. (Shows you how long I've been away from that project that I forgot that that was happening. :-( )

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Installer it's all about the component guids. If you had an install of 10 files they would all have unique component guids. If you do major upgrade to a product that no longer needs five of those files and substitutes five others, then obviously you don't put the old files in the upgrade, but also you add those five new files with five new component guids. In other words the symptoms suggest that you added new files but kept the existing component guids. A major upgrade includes an uninstall of the old product, but using the same component guids results in a ref count for the guid that never becomes zero to cause those components (and therefore the files) to be uninstalled.

Also, if the component was ever marked permanent or the files was ever marked shared then files will not removed. Marking the component permanent sticks it to the system, so rebuilding the MSI and marking it not permanent doesn't fix it. The component has an extra rec count. When a file is explicitly marked shared it means that it could be installed through a non-MSI install (and won't be component guid ref counted) so there will be an entry in SharedDlls in the registry because MSI has been told there is another non-MSI client. SharedDlls can be looked in the registry to see if that's happened. The ref count of a component is harder to discover, but a verbose log of the upgrade would help. This VB script will show all the installed components and the products that are using them:

```
Option Explicit
Public installer, fullmsg, comp, a, prod, fso, pname, ploc, pid, psorce
```

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fso.CreateTextFile("comps.txt", True)

' Connect to Windows Installer object
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
a.writeline ("MSI Components")
on error resume next
For Each comp In installer.components
   a.writeline (comp & " is used by the product:")
   for each prod in Installer.ComponentClients (comp) 
      pid = installer.componentpath (prod, comp) 
      pname = installer.productinfo (prod, "InstalledProductName")
      a.Writeline ("     " & pname & " " & prod & "and is installed at " & pid)
   Next
Next

`enter code here`

Comment: What about minor upgrades. As I said, in one of the 3 directories where .ASP files were replaced with corresponding .INC files, the .ASP file (only one in that case) was removed during the upgrade, while in the other two directories, none of the .ASP files were removed. In all 3 cases, the file entries were generated from a wildcard; in one of the cases that didn't work and in the one that did, the component name didn't change, and some other file was the key file. In the 3rd case, the component name did change, because there were only 2 .ASP->.INC files in the folder.

Comment: And none of the GUIDs changed for any of those 3 components. Incidentally, I tired changing the GUIDs of the two components where the removal of the old .ASP files didn't work, and the result was the same; the old .ASP files remained.